# iPhone does not show notifications for missed calls

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

At some point in the past couple of months, my iPhone 8 has stopped giving me notifications when I miss a call. No notification appears on the lock screen and no badge appears on the phone app signifying a missed call. I'm only able to see that I've missed a call if I open the phone app because it does still show as missed on the `Recents` tab. Oddly, the phone app does show a badge count when I get a voicemail.

I've seen posts on other sites mentioning this issue with no resolution, but it seemed like if it was wide spread Apple would have fixed it by now, so I'm assuming it's something specific to my phone/settings/etc. I've added the picture below showing my phone notification settings, which all seem to be correct for receiving notifications (sorry it's weirdly large).

[image]